# Can everyone resize their iframe the way CityVille does?

Tags: facebook

CityVille seems to have a version of the FB API that allows them to go 100% width/height within a Facebook iframe. Is this only for them? How can this be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've finally opened up fluid canvas size to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following javascript ?

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 600, height: 880 });
```

but before that you will need to go to the apps settings under advance tab and change your canvas option